# Repository type is missing/invalid

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

```
"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?repositoryId=<repository-name>&branchName={branchName}&api-version=7.0"
```

I see this error on running above API:

> Repository type is missing/invalid

What should I type as Repository type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository types you can find here: [RepositoryTypes Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.webapi.repositorytypes?view=azure-devops-dotnet).

for Azure DevOps Git use: **TfsGit**.

Additionally, check your repo Id with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP

Because with the repo name you`ll receive the following message:

[image]

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76125214/api-to-get-all-builds-based-on-repo-branch I see an issue with api to list all builds